# What does tools:ignore="UselessParent" mean in the Android XML layout file?

Tags: android, layout, lint

The code snippet:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dummy_button" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure `tools:ignore="UselessParent"` means. Does it mean when the lint finds the Button fills the `LinearLayout`, then the `LinearLayout` will be removed, and the Button will moved into the parent and let the view hierarchy efficient? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please see the [Reference Link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes) If my answer will help you then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case

`tools:ignore="UselessParent"`

tells your IDE to avoid displaying a message like this: *"This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless"*

Consider this case:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/detailLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/downloadFormsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/download_forms_button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/formErrorMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The LINT error message is displayed for the inner `RelativeLayout`.

To avoid the warning message go Build Path->Configure Build Path.... Under Android Lint Preferences look for UselessParent and set it's severity to ignore.

What is LINT? look here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html

**UPDATE:**

The prefix `tools:` is used by the IDE and it's not considered when the project is compiled.

Comment: I copied the code and followed your steps.And things happened exactly as you said.Very appreciate your answering style!

Comment: have fun here in stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

`UselessParent` is an Android lint issue identifier for a check that tries to figure out whether a parent layout can be removed.

`tools:ignore="UselessParent"` disables that check in the specified element and its children in case you want to suppress the lint message.